# Function designing

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions

What function $G(x)$ has the following properties?

1. $G$ is non-increasing.
2. $0\le G(x)\le1$ for all $x$.
3. $G(x)=1$ if $x=x_{\min}$; $G(x)=0$ if $x\ge x_{\max}$.
4. $G$ has a parameter $0\le k\le1$, and if $k$ decreases $G$ decreases faster.
5. $G(x)=0$ when $k=0$; $G(x)=1$ when $k=1$.
6. $G$ is simple as possible.

Comment: Piecewise function.

Comment: If $k$ decreasing should offer more rapid variation, does this not contradict the function having no variation when $k$ is at its minimum?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Actually this function is used for the  switching coefficient in control systems and when G(x)=0 it makes the fastest switching. Therefore statement 5 is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Statement 5 is inconsistent with the rest of the statements, but here's a function *G* satisfying all the other statements.

Define $m=\dfrac{x_{\min}+x_{\max}}2$, $a=x_{\min}+m(1-k)$ and $b=x_{\max}-m(1-k)$. Then
$$G(x)=\begin{cases}
1&x<a\\
\frac{b-x}{b-a}&a\le x\le b\\
0&x>b
\end{cases}$$
We can easily check that this function satisfies statements 1 to 4. Statement 6 is a little subjective, but since the $G$ defined here has three linear pieces, it's probably as simple as it can get.

Comment: G can be a multivariable function